# Azure Dev Ops - Site Under Construction Page during Web App Deployment

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment

I have a .NET MVC Website that gets automatically deployed based on a GIT repository checkin. (Azure Dev ops Pipeline)

When the website is being deployed, if I got to the website URL. I get a blank page with a "Site Under Construction title" page. After the deployment is complete, this page goes away and I see my site.

What I want to know is how can I customise this Under construction page.
If I add a app_offline.htm file in the root of my visual studio project. I seem to see this file when deploy is happening, but when its finished, the file is still there, and I can't see the site.

Do I need to make a change to my build pipeline somehow? or make a change to my web-app configration?

What do I need to do to have this file displayed only during the deployment.

Comment: Has your problem been solved? Is there any progress?

Comment: @JasonPan - Not yet. I will try and impent your updated answer today and see if it works. -Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

[1. Invoking MsDeploy.exe manually in a Azure Devops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59129145/invoking-msdeploy-exe-manually-in-a-azure-devops)

[2. App_Offline in MSBuild Remote Web Deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059109/app-offline-in-msbuild-remote-web-deploy)

**PRIVIOUS**

You can configure it in `.pubxml` file. That is actually used to take your app offline while deploying. After finishing deployment, MSDeploy tool should delete APP_OFFLINE.html automatically.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <EnableMSDeployAppOffline>true</EnableMSDeployAppOffline>
  ...
</PropertyGroup>
```

Related posts:

[1.  Automatize App Offline in Azure App Service and Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59161879/automatize-app-offline-in-azure-app-service-and-visual-studio)

**tlejmi's answer is very detailed.**

[2. How to take web app offline while publishing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20792405/how-to-take-web-app-offline-while-publishing)

[3. Getting site under construction message after azure webapp deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33045217/getting-site-under-construction-message-after-azure-webapp-deployment)

Comment: When you say configure in .pubxml where do I need to put that file? I'm not using MSDeploy, I am deploying with a azure dev ops... pipline